# Problem in Deleting Previous OS and Installing Parrot OS

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, parrotsec

i had installed parrot os by deleting window 10, Parrot OS stopped working after a few days because of some problem in installation. Now i want to DELETE the previous Parrot os and reinstall it via a USB flash derive.

I connected the derive and started installation on my ASUS laptop, during installation it asks me

***"This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later. If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here"***

while having two options "yes or no"

i DONT know what that means, Can someone help me with that? I have already backup my data.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems your previous installation was using BIOS mode and then you changed it to UEFI mode. You need to change that back to BIOS(Legacy) mode from boot menu. if you continue with UEFI it WON'T end well.

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/602hlq/having_a_lot_of_trouble_with_uefilegacy_when/) is the link to the possible solution in more details.